# How to pass by reference in two methods?

Tags: php, oop, reference

```
class foo {
    public $value1 = 1;

    public function setValue1(& $v) {
        $this->value1 = $v;
    }
}

class bar {
    public $value2 = 2;
    public $obj;

    public function & getValue2() {
        return $this->value2;
    }

    public function setValue2($v) {
        $this->value2 = $v;
}
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = new bar();

$bar->obj = $foo;

$foo->setValue1($bar->getValue2()); //<-- not works

//$foo->value1 =& $bar->getValue2(); //<-- works

$bar->setValue2(4);


var_dump($foo, $bar) Prints:
    object(foo)[124]
      public 'value1' => int 2
    object(bar)[123]
      public 'value2' => int 4
      public 'obj' => 
        object(foo)[124]
          public 'value1' => int 2
```

Why when I'm using $foo->setValue1($bar->getValue2()) a foo->value1 is equal 2 and bar->value2 is equal 4 ?

I'm trying to pass-by-reference and return-by-reference using methods instead of properties.

Comment: Please read the [PHP manual for returning references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), it states that "    Note: Unlike parameter passing, here you have to use & in both places - to indicate that you want to return by reference, not a copy, and to indicate that reference binding, rather than usual assignment, should be done for $myValue."  Try the line `$foo->setValue1(& $bar->getValue2());`

Comment: you need to use reference inside method $this->value1 = &$v;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is reference inside method $foo->value1 = &$v;

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

```
class foo {
    public $value1 = 1;

    public function &setValue1( $v ) { // <-- !
        $this->value1 = &$v; // <-- !
    }
}

class bar {
    public $value2 = 2;
    public $obj;

    public function &getValue2() {
        return $this->value2;
    }

    public function &setValue2( $v ) { // <-- !
        $this->value2 = $v;
}
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = new bar();

$bar->obj = $foo;

$tmp =& $bar->getValue2(); // <-- !
$foo->setValue1( &$tmp ); // <-- !

$bar->setValue2( 4 );

echo "<pre>" . print_r( $foo, 1 ) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . print_r( $bar, 1 ) . "</pre>";
```

→ *Output:*

```
foo Object
(
    [value1] => 4
)

bar Object
(
    [value2] => 4
    [obj] => foo Object
        (
            [value1] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: BIT CHEETAH, @Jon, please, read the NOTE here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: $foo->setValue1( &$tmp ); // <-- ! //Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed